# jQuery toggle class of the clicked element when hiding or showing other divs

Tags: jquery

I use below code to toggle some divs, is working.
I want to remove class "link" of the clicked element  and when is clicked other  element to remove also for it and to add it back to  previous one. The main  element whose is pressed should have the class removed, and all other not.

```
$(this).toggleClass("link") ...
```

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("#" + target).toggle().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cat-1" class="show">
  <div>
    <a class="link" rel="main-1" href="#">Main A</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cat-2" class="show">
  <div>
    <a class="link" rel="main-2" href="#">Main B</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cat-3" class="show">
  <div>
    <a class="link" rel="main-3" href="#">Main C</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="main-1" class="description" style="display:none;">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="main-2" class="description" style="display:none;">
    <p>et iusto odio dignissimos.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="main-3" class="description" style="display:none;">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this with a hide class instead of inline styles and hide() show() methods? It's easier to control. I'd suggest removing all hide classes then adding hide class to the "this" item to hide/show its siblings, or just use the ids.

Comment: To be honest, it's not that clear what you want to do.  Remove `link` when clicked - fine, but the rest doesn't make much sense.  Sounds like: Remove class `link` when clicked, when clicking another element remove from that element and add back to all others.

Comment: Sounds like: `$(this).closest(".show").siblings(".show").find("a").addClass("link"); $(this).removeClass("link")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check for the `link` class (`.hasClass`) and will toggle accordingly.

The parent div is found by looking for the id that starts with `"cat-"` (`"div[id^='cat-'] > div > a"`)

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {

if ($(this).hasClass("link")) {
  $("div[id^='cat-'] > div > a").addClass("link");
  $(this).closest("div").find("a").removeClass("link");
} else {
  $("div[id^='cat-'] > div > a").addClass("link");
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cat-1" class="show">
  <div>
    <a class="link" rel="main-1" href="#">Main A</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cat-2" class="show">
  <div>
    <a class="link" rel="main-2" href="#">Main B</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cat-3" class="show">
  <div>
    <a class="link" rel="main-3" href="#">Main C</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="main-1" class="description" style="display:none;">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="main-2" class="description" style="display:none;">
    <p>et iusto odio dignissimos.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="main-3" class="description" style="display:none;">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```